# C# ; using 2 known Var Names as Name for new public array

Tags: c#

I have 3 known elements:

1) Data Source name = DaSo

2) Function applied to Data Source name = Fun

3) Output Value = OuVa

The goal is to create a Public Var named by combining the two names of DaSo & Fun into a new public variable. Ultimately the end result should link like  ...

Public String DaSoFun = OuVa

... In C# script, what would be the least processor intensive way to perform the task?

Comment: Variables have names specified at compile-time, not execution time. Why do you care about the name of the variable? It's really unclear what your overall goal is.

Comment: Dotted names are not valid variable names. What is `FirstName.Name`? Why not just `string FirstName`? A var named `“FirstName.NameLastName.Name”`???? It is completely unclear what you are trying to achive.

Comment: I reframed the Question to be applicable to my situation... I tried to make the Question clear, and universally understood with out imposing on People’s sensibilities.  I am looking for the quickest processing time in C# to combine 3 known fields into a single public array.  The current solution I can not implement (too long to process). I am asking for a small component; I will be implementing the best structure over millions of iterations, smaller the better.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a type that can store those elements. Let's create a class named `Person` for this purpose

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double Age { get; set; }
}
```

With this declaration you can create an array, or better, a list of persons. Lists can grow, arrays are fixed size.

```
public List<Person> Persons { get; } = new List<Person>();
```

You can add a person like this

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 21.25 };
Persons.Add(person);
```

and you can access it like this within the list (or array)

```
var p = Persons[0];
Console.WriteLine($"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName}, age = {p.Age}");
```

---

I assume that what you want, is a kind of lookup by first and last name. In this case add this property to the `Person` class

```
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

And add the persons to a dictionary instead of a list. Use the full name as key and the person as value

```
public Dictionary<string, Person> Persons { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
```

The add a person like this

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 21.25 };
Persons.Add(person.FullName, person);
```

Now, you can look up a person like this

```
string searchFor = "John Doe";
if (Persons.TryGetValue(searchFor), out Person p)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"The age of {p.FullName} is {p.Age}.");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine($"No person named {searchFor} found.");
}
```

Comment: How would“FirstNameLastName” double value be detectable?

Comment: “FirstNameLastName” = Age ... after this little portion of script runs in tandem with another script that Incorperated the out put. This data point has to be tracked as“JohnDoe”... How will that portion run a Get(Person) when it needs specifically John Doe or Jane Doe, or some other combo?

Comment: I added an example showing how you can create a new property that combines two other properties and how you can use a dictionary to lookup persons by name.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, hopefully some one finds this answer helpful.  I was unclear when I asked the Question originally.  Again thank you for your efforts.